# Node.js - Transfer Large Files Without Consuming A Lot of Memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

**Motive :** Transfer Files of around 10gb to 50gb from client to server using node

**Problem :** Consuming a lot of memory sometimes reaches around 6gb and system hangs

**What I want is :** my code should not use more than 200mb of ram..

**What I Am Doing :** I pause my stream when ram usage reaches 200 mb

**Expected :** That I am gonna pause streaming data when ram usage reaches 200 mb and will Resume it when usage comes down.

**What's happening :** I pauses when usage is above 200 mb but it does not resumes cos even the script is pause the ram usage is not comming down.

Client.js

```
  var net = require('net'),
   fs = require('fs'),
  path = require('path');

  socket = new net.Socket();
  socket.connect(6000, 127.0.0.1);
  socket.on('connect',function(){

 // I am reading around 10 gb of file in chunks

 var readStream = fs.createReadStream("File Name", {highWaterMark: 16384});

  // Checking ram usage every second to ensure it does not consume more than 200 mb of ram, If i do not write this check it even uses 4gb+ ram for this much big file and hangs my node script.

  setInterval(function(){
    if(process.memoryUsage().rss > 209715200){
        // if ram consumtion is more that 200 mb
        console.log("Pause");
        global.gc();
        readStream.pause();
    }else{
        readStream.on('pause',function(){
          readStream.resume();
        });
    }
  },1000);

 readStream.on('data', function(chunk){

   console.log("Used Mem "+process.memoryUsage().rss);
   var head = new Buffer.from("FILE");
   var sizeHex = chunk.length.toString(16);
   while(sizeHex.length < 4){
     sizeHex = "0" + sizeHex;
   }
   var size = new Buffer.from(sizeHex);
   var delimiter = new Buffer.from("@");
   var pack = Buffer.concat([head, size, chunk, delimiter]);
     // sending data to server
     // This sending part start consuming ram 
     socket.write(pack,function(){
     });
 });

 readStream.on('close', function(){
   socket.end();
   global.gc();
 });


 });
```

Server.js

```
  var net = require('net'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  path = require('path');

  var server = net.createServer(function(socket){
    var packets = 0;
    var buffer = new Buffer.alloc(0);
// Receiving Data
    socket.on('data', function(chunk){
      buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, chunk]);
    });


// when Client socket ends write file on server 
    socket.on('close', function(){

      var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("New File Name");
      while(buffer.length){
        var head = buffer.slice(0, 4);

        if(head.toString() != "FILE"){
          console.log("ERROR!!!!");
          process.exit(1);
        }

        var sizeHex = buffer.slice(4, 8);
        var size = parseInt(sizeHex, 16);


        var content = buffer.slice(8, size + 8);
        var delimiter = buffer.slice(size + 8, size + 9);

        if(delimiter != "@"){
          console.log("wrong delimiter!!!");
          process.exit(1);
        }
        writeStream.write(content);
        buffer = buffer.slice(size + 9);
      }

      setTimeout(function(){
        writeStream.end();
      }, 2000);

    });   

  });

   server.listen(6000);
```

**Ram Usage in system Monitor**

```
  Before Running Above Script : 1.6gb of 6 gb 
  After Running Above Script : 1.8 gb of 6gb
```

Comment: Have you tried unsetting pack after writing it to socket so gc can pick it up? Like: `delete pack; global.gc();`

Comment: @DamirKasipovic Tried it But Still same issue

Comment: What node.js version are you using?

Comment: I am Using node v10.6.0 @m1ch4ls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are not waiting for `socket.write` to finish... The callback in `socket.write` is there to signal that writing has finished and you can send another chunk.

Instead of manually writing to socket use [`pipe`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) or [`pipeline`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_streams_callback) to manage the streaming for you.

This is my take:

`client.js`

```
const net = require('net');
const fs = require('fs');
const { pipeline } = require('stream');

const socket = new net.Socket();
socket.connect(6000, '127.0.0.1');
socket.on('connect', function () {
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('/dev/zero', { highWaterMark: 16384, end: 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 }); // read 2GB of zeros, replace with real file
  console.log('New file transfer');

  pipeline(
    fileStream,
    socket,
    (error) => {
      if (error) { console.error(error) }
      console.log('File transfer done');
    }
  );
});
```

`server.js`

```
const net = require('net');
const fs = require('fs');
const { pipeline } = require('stream');

const server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
  const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream('/dev/null');
  console.log('New file transfer');

  pipeline(
    socket,
    fileStream,
    (error) => {
      if (error) { console.error(error) }
      console.log('File transfer done');
    }
  )
});

server.listen(6000);
```

From what I have tested it never exceeds 100MB in RAM and overall the code behaves reasonably - so no `gc` and memory checks are necessary.

The code above is using `pipeline` function that is available only in latest Node.js 10 - in case you use older Node use [pump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pump) package that works the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this seems useful but with change in client.js code now i am not able to use the old server.js code which i was using to receive data i.e. `socket.on('data',function(chunk){ .     buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, chunk]);
});` Link to complete file can you tell me what changes i need to make in order to receive file 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Oi6rXlb6fVsBk9uIH51f34NCrY75nQ3O/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Maybe ask another question - I am not sure what are you trying to do - the transfer protocol looks weird to me. Why do you want to pack each `chunk` with header and size? Send and received chunks are not the same...

Comment: And When I run above code with my old server.js which was working with my previous code it consoles `undefined` in terminal which is because of console.log(error)... that means some error occured ... thanks

Comment: Fixed the answer - it means not error has occurred if it's `undefined`

Comment: Thanks a lot... I edited my above question and gave some more details about the server file too... can you please help me making changes in server file too so that even server side should not use ram alot and can run with your code too... thanks a lot...

Comment: By the way this server file worked too with your client.js code but what is the proper method of doing this by taking care of ram consumption too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178566/discussion-between-neeraj-walia-and-m1ch4ls).

Comment: I want your help again [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550132/node-js-encrypt-and-decrypt-file]