# Node js - Encrypt and Decrypt File

Tags: node.js, encryption

> I want to encrypt File on client side and send it to server side and
>   decrypt

But When I am using node js inbuilt [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) I am getting Error

client.js

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes192', 'a password');
const encInput = fs.createReadStream("abc.txt");
const encOutput = fs.createWriteStream("abc.txt.enc");

       encInput.pipe(cipher).pipe(encOutput).on('close', function() {
         // DATA SENT TO SERVER SIDE
         //USING PIPELINE TO SEND DATA TO SERVER
       });
```

This part is done perfectly it creates an ecrypted file on client side and sends it to server side

Server.js

`//receive Data`

`//AFTER RECEIVING FILE ON this side I run decrypt script`

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes192', 'a password');

const decInput = fs.createReadStream("abc.txt.enc");
const decOutput = fs.createWriteStream("abc.txt");
decInput.pipe(decipher).pipe(decOutput);
```

And this gives an error

```
Error: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
    at Decipher._flush (internal/crypto/cipher.js:141:28)
    at Decipher.prefinish (_stream_transform.js:141:10)
    at Decipher.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at prefinish (_stream_writable.js:630:14)
    at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:638:5)
    at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:481:3)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:471:7)
    at Decipher.afterTransform (_stream_transform.js:94:3)
    at Decipher._transform (internal/crypto/cipher.js:136:3)
    at Decipher.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:190:10)
    Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Decipher.onerror (_stream_readable.js:687:12)
    at Decipher.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at done (_stream_transform.js:208:19)
    at _flush (_stream_transform.js:142:7)
    at Decipher._flush (internal/crypto/cipher.js:143:5)
    at Decipher.prefinish (_stream_transform.js:141:10)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:481:3)
```

**I know there is no problem on client side it is working perfectly sending data using pipeline socket**

**No problem in receiving data too on server side only the decryption is creating problem and idk why **

> Anything else you want to know about my code please tell
>
> Using Node v10.6.0

Comment: Compare the `abc.txt.enc` file on client and on the server after upload. Are they equal? Both files in the same encoding?

Comment: @Lemix Yes Both are same... what I saw now is on server side it decrypts file perfectly but after that gives this error...

Comment: What I Now found is when I decrypt file made on client side with the same code it works fine but if I decrypt file which I received on server side with the same code it gives me this error

Comment: Try with initialization vector (`createCipheriv` and `createDecipheriv` methods). Example in my answer.

Comment: I reproduced a similar error. I managed to solve it only by using base64 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Try with initialization vector and `base64` file storage format:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const base64 = require('base64-stream');
const iv = new Buffer('1065faf25ac8560968c58ce6dc0ae36f', 'hex'); // 16 byte iv
const kk = new Buffer('84521db468d282c4ce21cdde65e508ce3d1924d1be5c4754', 'hex'); // 24 byte key (192 bits)
const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes192', kk, iv, { encoding: 'base64' });
const encInput = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, "abc.txt"));
const encOutput = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, "abc.txt.enc"));

encInput.pipe(cipher).pipe(encOutput).on('close', function () {
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes192', kk, iv);
    const decInput = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, "abc.txt.enc"));
    const decOutput = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, "abc.txt.dec"));
    decInput.pipe(base64.decode()).pipe(decipher).pipe(decOutput);
});
```

Comment: Still Same error ... the code I posted above is giving problem decoding the file I send to server side if I do encryption and decryption on same side it is not giving me any error but when I encrypt file on client side and send it to server and decrypt it on server side it produces error .... though it decrypts file and it works fine but gives me error which exits server file and I am not able to carry on with the more stuff i want to do below... I tried urs one but same problem ... thanks for your effort

Comment: @NeerajWalia In my example if I use `encode: utf8` when encryption, I get your error. As a result, the file created with the encoding specified is identical to the file without the encoding specified, but gives an error. Maybe this information will be helpful.

Comment: when i use your code exactly it works fine but you are doing enc and dec inside same file let's say client.js... but i want to send the file from client to server and I am doing that using pipeline so I want enc on client and dec on server side sending file using stream,pipeline,socket...